# Functional equation with two variables: $ f(x) - f(y) = (x+y)(x-y) $

Tags: functions, quadratics, functional-equations

> Find all functions that, for all real numbers $ x $ and $ y $, satisfy the following functional equation:
>
> $$ f(x) - f(y) = (x+y)(x-y) $$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $f(x) - x^2 = f(y) - y^2$, so this must be ...

Comment: I'm not sure could you factorise that maybe?

Comment: $f(x) - f(0) = x^2$ and hence $f(x) = f(0) + x^2$. The function is of the form $f(x) = k+x^2$ for any constant $k$. There are infinitely many functions satisfying the given condition.

Comment: Sorry could you please explain why $f(x) - f(0) = x^2$ ?

Comment: Added an answer with explanation.

Comment: The point is that the right side doesn't depend on $x$ (or, if you prefer, the left side doesn't depend on $y$), so $f(x) - x^2$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Putting $y=0$, we get $f(x)−f(0)= (x+0)(x-0) = x^2$ and hence $f(x)=f(0)+x^2$. The function is of the form $f(x)=k+x^2$ for any constant $k$. There are infinitely many functions satisfying the given condition.

Comment: Oh I get it now, thanks for the clarification. I also tried the inverse (subbing in y = 0) and that also worked. Just to be clear, would I need to substitute in any other values to prove the validity of my argument?

Comment: No. We have already got the function expression.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)-f(y)=(x+y)(x-y)$$

so:
$$f(x)-f(y)=x^2-y^2$$
and:
$$f(x)-x^2=f(y)-y^2$$
Left Side has only $x$ and Right Side has $y$ argument and each side is equal to another, so both sides must be equal to a Constant, like $K^2$.

so:
$$f(x)-x^2=f(y)-y^2 = K^2$$
and:
$$
f(x)=x^2 + K^2\\
f(y)=y^2 + K^2
$$